# Button Click not working in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

All,
I am using `clickAndWait xpath=//button[contains(.,'Next')]`, it does show when i click find on Selenium IDE but doesn't click on the Button. The button has id = pmc_wizard_next and class = btn btn-next.

The html for the button is:

```
<div id="pmc_wizard" class="wizard pmc-wizard">

    <ul class="steps pmc-wizard-steps"> … </ul>
    <div class="actions pmc-wizard-actions">
        <button id="pmc_wizard_prev" class="btn btn-prev"> … </button>
        <button id="pmc_wizard_next" class="btn btn-next" data-last="Submit">

            Next

            <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

In my case, when the button is clicked it doesn't navigate it to the next page however it does perform all the actions on the next page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

clickAndWait generally gives the timeout error . you can either use

```
click|target|
waitForElementPresent|the next element that could be possibly reached after click|
```

hope this answer would help you!